# Status of RTMP streams

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to understand meaning and status of rtmp streams. I see some tracks have both mp3 and rtmp streams, but I don't understand why and what stream should I use.

What reasons to give both streams? Is where are any sounds without mp3 stream?  Should I use rtmp stream if it available or not?

Is it okay to play only mp3 stream?

Answer (score 1):

Not all clients support RTMP, which is why both streams are offered. You can use whichever you like, but there's indeed going to be tracks that do not have an mp3 stream.